# How to return data that was sent to me in the form of a callback?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm not entirely familiar with web development, so this might seem like a stupid question, but allow me to describe it.

After the user has chosen what they want to purchase, an API call was made that generated a trans_id and redirected to the bank's page where the payment was processed. Regardless of whether the response is positive or negative, we were redirected to a callback URL from after the payment. In our case, this is /transaction/callback.

We want to get the trans_id that we see in network -> callback -> payload

That is my code where we have to get the trans_id

Next Js app router 14.0.4

```
  "use client"
  import React from 'react';

  export default function Page() {
    return (
      <div className='flex items-center justify-center w-full min-h-[100vh]'>
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <h2 className="text-center text-white text-[35px] font-medium font-['Manrope'] uppercase">The order has been taken</h2>
            <p className="text-center mt-4 text-white text-lg font-light font-['Manrope']">All information regarding your order has been sent to the indicated email.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

After receiving this trans_id, we will make a request to another API to check the status. The problem is that I don't quite understand how to extract it.

Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what you've shared it does not return a callback but is rather done with a api request. Can you please share more of your code.

If it is indeed a callback redirect (which i doubt because formData cannot be sent with a get request.) then you should consult the documentation of your payment provider.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you make an API call , there will be a response. From the network tab, you can see that a response was being sent back to you.

Ultimately in ReactJS or basically Javascript you should use something like a

```js
const response = await fetch('https://cricova.lol/transaction/callback');
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
```

in that data variable you should be able to access that data object to obtain the trans_id key that you want.

Comment: Why do you have an alt account that has existed longer than [your active one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17051142/jcommando)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it helped me understand better how it works. However, we can't capture the information from the callback on the client side. At least, I haven't found a way to do it via the client. Instead, I created an API with a POST request /transaction/callback, where I retrieve the trans_id. I changed my file from page.js to route.js, and it worked. Thank you again.